# js remove certain words that don't match

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js string...

```
var string = "Hi how are you <b>today</b>";
```

I now have a new js string...

```
var newstring = "are today";
```

I want to remove all the words from `var string` that don't match `var newstring`. I would also like to keep the tags that are associated with those words, if any.

```
Example Result:
are <b>today</b>
```

Comment: You're going to want to use regex that you'll build up on the fly based on the comparison string, also it will help in perserving html tags however it can be complicated for anything other than simple html tags. You may have to break it down word by word and check against a list and see if you can parse out html.

Comment: If you are looking to preserve the html tags, make sure your test string also contains the required tags. A good way to do this would be to use the html() jquery methods. Then its as simple as using replace like lneetho's answer, as the tags will be returned as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some simpe ways to do something like this, if they will work for you depends on what you intend to use this for, but something like this maybe:

```
var string = "Hi how are you <b>today</b>",
    newstring = "are today",
    words = newstring.split(' ');

for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
    var reg = new RegExp(words[i], 'gi');
    string = string.replace(reg, '');
}

console.log(string);​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ddfeq/)

Comment: If I want to combine var string into a var instead of console.log(string); so I can output the final result, what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: The variable string is not an array, you can just output it any way you'd like, see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ddfeq/2/). If you need to keep the original string as well, create a new variable for replacing etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "Hi how are you <b>today</b>",
    newstring = "are today",
    words= newstring.split(' ');
$.each(words, function(i, v) {
    if(new RegExp(v, 'ig').test(string) && !new RegExp('<b>'+v+'</b>', 'ig').test(string)) {
        string = string.replace(v,'');
    }
});
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var source = "Hi how are you <b>today</b>",
    pattern = "are today",
    res = [];

pattern.split(/\s+/).forEach(function( word ) {
    source.split(/\s+/).forEach(function( sWord ) {
        if( ~sWord.indexOf(word) ) res.push( sWord );
    });
});

console.log(res.join(' '));
```

Comment: +1 for using `~` but this will match things that are not the word though, like `Hi how are you <b>today</b>, aren't you hungry?`. `aren't` would match even though its not one of the words. Of course in that same case mine would spit out 2 `are`s :/

Comment: What's the benefit of using the `~`? I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'Hi how are you <b>today</b>',
    words = ['are', 'today']; //or 'are today'.split(' '),
    regex = new RegExp('(<[a-zA-Z]*>)?(' + words.join('|') + ')(</[a-zA-Z]*>)?', 'g');

console.log(regex, str.match(regex), str.match(regex).join(' '));
```

You will need a more complex regex to capture all HTML tags though.

http://jsfiddle.net/g7xQx/